# Ошибка (AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'TeleBot')

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал эхо-бота, запускаю через питоновскую оболочку, и пишет ошибку. Помогите, пожалуйста.
Вот код:

```
import telebot
import configure

bot = telebot.TeleBot (configure.config['token'])

@bot.message_handler (content_types = ['text'])
def echo (message):

    bot.send_message (message.chat.id, message.text)
bot.polling (none_stop = True)
```

Comment: Пробовал запускать ещё через консоль. Не выходило, писало такую ошибку: (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot')

Comment: 1. Прежде чем копипастить из интегрировать, неплохо бы ознакомиться с азами языка. Тебе вчера уже рекомендовали.  2. Прежде чем задать вопрос, неплохо бы для начала самостоятельно попытаться найти ответ.

Comment: @Эникейщик Небось ошибка с который пожалуй все начинающие на питоне столкнулись (ну по-крайне мере начинающие без большого креатива по именованию файлов): Файл то небось тоже `telebot.py` ;)

Comment: пробовал найти ответ, не выходило, я не копипастил

Comment: мой файл так не назван - telebot.py

Comment: @Nodwidch не пробовал. Даже на этом сайте есть несколько вопросов по точно такой же ошибке. Если бы пробовал, то нашёл бы.

Comment: я смотрел, ответов не находил. и вообще мне вы поможете или нет?

Comment: кто-то опечатался, у кого-то ошибка заключалась в другом.

Comment: и ошибка у меня сейчас другая, а не вчерашняя.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install PyTelegramBotApi==3.7.2
```

либо

```
pip3 install PyTelegramBotApi
```

Если запускаете код с Pycharm - перезапустите его, либо через сам Pycharm в разделе terminal выполните команды выше

Comment: Для windows просто `pip install PyTelegramBotApi`

Comment: Спасибо, через pip3 install PyTelegramBotApi получилось!